# Create custom queue

Tags: c, asterisk

I've been looking into making a new queue strategy for my asterisk installation, my first project is to join the features of leastrecent and roundrobin in one queue.

I've found a lot of 3rd party callcenter solutions, but haven't been able to determine if any of them uses other strategies than the standards.

So far my thought is that i have to create my own module that adds the functionality. The documentation on creating modules is scarce, besides a well written guide by Russel Bryant.

Is it possible to make some sort of an extention to an existing module, or would i have to replace et completely?

Is there documentation of any sort about creating your own queue strategy ?

i'm running asterisk 11

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can change queue.

Read  apps/app_queue.c and extend it as needed. If you have enought skill to extend and TEST queue(multithreaded app), then have be no any issues read app_queue.c

Other solution is use AMI with AsyncAGI call.

http://www.moythreads.com/wordpress/2007/12/24/asterisk-asynchronous-agi/

PS. if you have question like that it is highly not recommended create callcenter. Read more books about asterisk and hire hi-skilled expert to help you. Otherwise very likly CC will not work ok under load.

Comment: i've been making some changes to app_queue.c in an attempt to do this before, but i'd like to isolate my own code from the pre existing code.
Would it be enough to read up on c to figure out how to extend the app_queue.c ?

Comment: Not think there is any way fully isolate your code. You can do patch. You can fork code,create other app(like app_queue2.c) Or use non-coding variants like AsyncAGI.